# Php code is running for the first entry in database but not for subsequent values, the answer shown is null

Tags: php, mysql, database, hash

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password', 'db');
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE hash='" . $hash . "'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1);

// If successfully queried 
if ($result1) {
  // Count how many row has this passkey
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

  // if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "temp_members_db"
  if ($count == 1) {
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $fname = $rows['first'];
    $lname = $rows['last'];
    $industry = $rows['industry'];
    $country = $rows['country'];
    $state = $rows['state'];
    $city = $rows['city'];
    $zip = $rows['zip'];
    $email = $rows['email'];
    $hash = $rows['hash'];
    $cc = $rows['countrycode'];
    $mobile = $rows['mobile'];
    $pwd = SHA1($rows['password']);

    // Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members" 
   $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password', 'db');

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$fname','$lname','$industry','$country','$state','$city','$zip','$email','$hash','$cc','$mobile','$pwd')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2);
  } else {
    echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
  }
  if ($result2) {
    echo "Your account has been activated";
    // Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey 
    $sql3 = "DELETE FROM temp_users WHERE hash='" . $hash . "'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql3);
  }
}
?>
```

This code is running only when the database is empty and once value is inserted in the database, the code stops running for subsequent entries. It is basically the code for email verification.

Comment: See your log files and if it doesn't help you yet, post the logs here.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is my log, unable to understand it:122.166.179.35 - - [13/Apr/2016:12:29:43 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 386 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"